# How visualize output cluster with each cluster unique colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

i just newb in python

i have code searching on internet for execute K-means use scikit, i have tried modified the code for visualize plot 3d and colour each cluster (3 cluster), but the result is for all cluster with same colour, the code and visualize below :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from collections import Counter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from pylab import *

X = np.array([[1, 2, 5],
              [5, 8, 2],
              [1.5, 1.8, 6],
              [8, 8, 9],
              [1, 0.6, 10],
              [2.5, 3.8, 6],
              [2.5, 5.8, 9],
              [5, 8, 3],
              [4, 0.6, 7],
              [2.5, 1.8, 4.6],
              [6.5, 1.8, 12],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [2, 0.6, 7],
              [5.5, 1.8, 4],
              [4.8, 6.9, 6],
              [4.9, 9.8, 2],
              [9, 11, 12]])


cluster_num = 3

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=cluster_num)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print "centroids : "
print centroids
print "labels : "
print labels

colors = ["g.","r.","c.","y."]

color = np.random.rand(cluster_num)

c = Counter(labels)


fig = figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    print "i : ",i
    print "color[labels[i]] : ",color[labels[i]]
    ax.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1], X[i][2], c=color[labels[i]])


for cluster_number in range(cluster_num):
  print("Cluster {} contains {} samples".format(cluster_number, c[cluster_number]))

ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], centroids[:, 2], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]
how can i make visualize for each cluster have own color? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now `color = np.random.rand(cluster_num)` is generating three random numbers and in `ax.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1], X[i][2], c=color[labels[i]])` you are trying to assign those random numbers as colors.

Instead, you can change `color = ["g", "r", "b"]` so that first cluster will be green, second will be red and third will be blue.

For cluster centers, pass the same parameter:

```
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], centroids[:, 2], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 100, c=color)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @ayhan, how show coordinate each point at scatter plot ? thx